# Do i need to create migration in Laravel for already exist tables in database?

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I'm new in Laravel world!
I created a Database in MySql with 8 Tables!
now i just want to know that do I need to create Migration for all 8 tables?
or just need to create model for each table?

Comment: Read more details about this  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations

Comment: yup!  i found out there is no need to create migration for already exists  tables (thats in db).

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you. If you don't need migration for those tables (ie. for testing/seeding, migration to another database or creating new local setup), then it is not necessary.

Also models are not required but if you want to use Eloquent and other fancy Laravel things, then create them.

From my point of view there is no reason to not have migrations and models.